# javascript - Failed to execute 'drawImage' on CanvasRenderingContext2D (JCrop)

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, jcrop

I am having an issue while drawing a canvas from the image which is already sitting on the html.
When I draw the cavas or extend the JCrop highlighted handles or move them then it shows this error "failed to execute 'drawimage' on 'canvasrenderingcontext2d' no function was found that matched the signature provided"

Please check my code below.

```
$("div.jcrop img").Jcrop({
    onChange: showPreview,
    onSelect: showPreview,
    setSelect: [100, 100, 50, 50]
});
function showPreview(c) {
    if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
        // Show image preview
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj = $("div.jcrop img")[0];
        var canvas = $("#preview")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(imageObj, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Did you look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973282/canvas-drawimage-returns-no-function-was-found-that-matched-the-signature-pr