# Canvas 'drawImage' returns ' No function was found that matched the signature provided.'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have two HTML5 canvases. I draw first on a temp one and then I want to copy the temp to the final one. 
Everything seems to work except the drawImage function which is weird because it accepts Images as well Canvases. I tried already the convert to DatatoUrl() method with no success.

These are the objects I am using. Sizes etc are all set later.

```
var paint = $('<canvas/>');
var temp_paint = $('<canvas/>');
temp_ctx = temp_paint[0].getContext('2d');
ctx = paint[0].getContext('2d');
```

Any ideas?

This is the code

```
function paintMouseUp(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    draw=false; 
    ctx.drawImage(temp_paint, 0, 0);
    temp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, settings.width, settings.height);
    mousePoints = [];
}
```

This is the error I am getting:
*Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.*

Comment: Already googled multiple times without solution. Also stated that I already did the image method as presented in that link. I suspect it is something do to with jQuery and DOM.

Comment: Yes, I have finally seen that you pass jQuery's object as `.drawImage()` first argument. Try `temp_paint[0]` or `temp_ctx.canvas` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. temp_ctx.canvas did the trick. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Since it is correct answer, either I should post it as normal answer or you can delete question. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: Normal answer would be preferable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp_paint` is jQuery's object, so it can't be `.drawImage()` first argument. You can use this code instead:

```
ctx.drawImage(temp_ctx.canvas, 0, 0);
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v4vey667/)